# Annoying tkinter pop up menu

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey I want to just display this message how do I get rid of the `tk` window that pops up every time the message pops up.

[image]

```
root= Tk()
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('anything')
root.mainloop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
messagebox.showinfo("Title", "Text")
```